# Access array inside another array of a datasource

Tags: html, angular, angular-material-table

```
 <wrapper-table [dataSource]="onlyScenarios"
                 [columns]="columns"
    <ng-container matColumnDef="workingPlaces">
        <th mat-header-cell
            *matHeaderCellDef
            scope="col">{{ 'MENU' | translate }}</th>
        <td mat-cell
            *matCellDef="let row">
            {{row.workingPlace}}
        </td>
    </ng-container>
```

I have this template and my datasource (onlyScenarios) is an array that contains another array (scenarios). As you can see in the mat-cell, i display the content of that object ({{row.workingPlace}}) but i need to display from the second array(scenarios). I mean something like

```
{{row.scenarios.workingPlace}}
```

The 'onlyScenarios' looks like this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/pp0tQ.jpg

How can i do that?

Comment: What does onlyScenarios look like?

Comment: @MathewBerg https://imgur.com/a/VQhN8nP looks like this

Comment: That looks like a subset. Is onlyScenarios an array? Can you update the question with some mock data?

Comment: @MathewBerg onlyScenarios is an array and also scenarios is array

Comment: That image still only shows just a snippet of onlyScenarios, if it's also an array it should have more data.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/oMzbzEH is this what you mean ?

Comment: Yeah. See my answer, unless you want all the scenarios?

Answer (score 0):

If scenarios is also an array then to access it to you have to make sure you access that entry:

```
{{row.scenarios[0].workingPlace}}
```

Something like this.

Answer (score -1):

That sounds good, just be sure that your [dataSource] contains only the scenario array and not the object you posted

Comment: i already pass the onlyScenarios from another array as input. 
''[onlyScenarios]="day.dayRoomScenario". Is there a way to send from here as 'day.dayRoomScenario.scenario' ?

Comment: Is the component you are using is made for that kind of behavior? Can you post the documentation of the component?

Comment: Here is an example of what your are looking for: [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nested-mat-table-wposk5?file=app%2Ftable-expandable-rows-example.html)

Comment: Thanks! I will take a look